# How to declare dependency which has different profiles in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have one project which has multiple modules. Here's project structure:

```
project:
  module_1
  module_2
```

module_1 has 2 profile: profile_1 and profile_2, both profile declare different properties and dependencies. module_2 depends on module_1.

Now I'd like to build the whole project, but from what I see is that the properties defined in profiles of module_1 is not visible by module_2. Because module_2 complains for that.

Is there anything I did wrong here ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What Maven command are you executing when you run your build?

Comment: mvn clean package -Pprofile_1

Comment: First why do you have properties which are needed in the module2? Why are you using profiles to build your project? What is the reason for that ? Can you show the pom file please? And describe what the real problem is?